# *.storyboard and standard *.xib

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, uistoryboard

I want to make horizontal paging in my app and I found that I can use `UIPageViewController`, but it's only for storyboard.

Can I use my old *.xibs, but write command to use after transition storyboard (if device has ios5) or xib (if device has older firmware)? If yes, how?
I want to make it here:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        if (purchased == 1 && [indexPath row] == 1) {

        } else if (iOSversion > 5) {
//Use storyboard
} else{
            DetailsViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
            detailViewController.item = [rssItems objectAtIndex:floor(indexPath.row)];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
            [detailViewController release];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple way to check whether the iOS version is 5:

```
#define IOS_5 [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] hasPrefix:@"5"]
```

Then just use:

```
if (IOS_5)
```

(Of course, when iOS 6 comes out you'd have to do a little more parsing.)

Comment: I know it, but I don't know, how to use storyboard.

Comment: -1 this is never the recommended way to check for device and framework capabilities.